# Как правильно передать ссылку?

Tags: php, yii2

В базе хранится поле link (string(2048)).
Во view добавляю link в тег а.

```
Html::a(ссылка, $myObject->link, ['target'=>'_blank'])
```

Проблема:
Если вставлять ссылку такого вида:
https://stackoverflow.com/
то ссылка откроет сайт "stackoverflow.com", а если вставить в таком виде:
stackoverflow.com
то открывает https://my-domain.loca/stackoverflow.com

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы вне зависимости от вида ссылки открывались сайты(хоть и не правильные) без моего домена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам мог бы подойти вариант с условием. Например:

```
Html::a(ссылка, 
(stristr($myObject->link, 'http') ? $myObject->link : 'https://'.$myObject->link),
['target'=>'_blank']);
```

Если у вас в ссылке есть http, то она подставится в таком виде, в каком есть, а если нет, то она конкатенируется с `https://` (замените на `http://` если вам это важно) и все равно будет иметь вид `https://link-to-somewhere.com`